# how to get values from fully qualified data type?

Tags: c#

I have Program.cs class like this

```
var products = new List<object>();
var f1 = new Fruit("Apple", 25.34, 5);
products.Add(f1);

foreach (var item in products)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

and this is my Fruit.cs class

```
public Fruit(string name, double weight, int quantity)
{
   Name = name;
   Weight = weight;
   Quantity = quantity;
}

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public double Weight { get; set; }

  public int Quantity { get; set; }
```

when i run this program this is written on the screen

```
ConsoleApplication1.Fruit
```

my question is how to print the values (Apple,25.34,5) which I stored in my products list?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you storing your object in `List<object>`, Use a `List<Fruits>` and then you can access each property inside your foreach loop.

Comment: Because i intent to use the same list for other class too. e.g Vegetables instead of fruit.

Comment: Create a base class, and combine related properties from `Fruits` and `Vegitable` in that class, Then have a `List<BaseClass>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the ToString() method:

```
public override ToString()
{
    return this.Name + "," + this.Weight + "," + this.Quantity
}
```

Comment: is there any other way instead of overriding the ToString Method?

Comment: @Junaid: all given answers here so far are correct, it's up to you to pick the solution you like most .

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
foreach (var item in products)
{
   Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Name: {0}, Weight: {1}, Quantity: {2}",
                                  ((Fruit)item).Name, 
                                  ((Fruit)item).Weight, 
                                  ((Fruit)item).Quantity));
}
```

or you could override the `ToString` method of `Fruits` class:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Weight { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public Fruit(string name, double weight, int quantity)
    {
       Name = name;
       Weight = weight;
       Quantity = quantity;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Name: {0}, Weight: {1}, Quantity: {2}", Name, Weight, Quantity);
    }
}
```

and live your `foreach` statement as it is:

```
foreach (var item in products)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

The reason why you get `ConsoleApplication1.Fruits` is because the default implemenation of the `ToString` method, that is called under the hood in the `Console.WriteLine` above, returns the full name of type of the object. Overriding this method, you can make it to return whatever your want.

Comment: thnx i have changed my class name and edited the code here as well.

Comment: @Junaid you mean using the `foreach` with `item.Name` etc?

Comment: Yes I cannot access fields like item.Name. its showing error.

Comment: @Junaid oops :( ! You are correct, we have to make a cast there. If you try the updated one, it will work. Thanks !

Comment: Ok i'll try that too.

Comment: Same problem. showing error again. its ok dude. i asked this question to see if there is any other method instead of overriding ToString method.

Comment: @Junaid something goes wrong today :). Please try the updated one and you will notice that works.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```
foreach (var item in products)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Weight: {1}, Quantity: {2}",
                                  ((Fruit)item).Name, 
                                  ((Fruit)item).Weight, 
                                  ((Fruit)item).Quantity);
}
```

or you can override your ToString method in Fruit Class and change it like this

```
public override string ToString()
{
     return Name+":"+Weight+":"+Quantity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write: Console.WriteLine(item.Name, item.Weight, item.Quantity);

More information:
Each item in the products list is of type Fruit. So if you want to print the right information, you need to access the properties (Name, Weight, Quantity) of the Fruit (item) object.

```
foreach (var item in products)
{
   Console.WriteLine((Fruit)item.Name, (Fruit)item.Weight, (Fruit)item.Quantity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
var products = new List<object>();
```

to

```
var products = new List<Fruits>();
```

so that you can write like this so will display like a table:

```
 var products = new List<object>();
        var f1 = new Fruits("Apple", 25.34, 5);
        var f2 = new Fruits("Orange", 18.19, 3);
        products.Add(f1);
        products.Add(f2);
        String ss = "Item\t\tWeight\t\tQty\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) ss += "-";

        Console.WriteLine(ss);

        foreach (var item in products)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name.ToString() + "\t\t" + item.Weight.ToString() + "\t\t" + item.Quantity.ToString());
        }
```